# Question for "Only if" part for the theorem "A language is Turing-recognizable iff some enumerator enumerates it."

Tags: turing-machines

I am trying to prove the theorem

> A language is Turing-recognizable iff some enumerator enumerates it.

I proved the "if" part, but I have no idea of proving the "only if" part, so I searched a proof for the "only if" part of this theorem. In the proof that I found,  it says

> Let $\sum$ be the alphabet of the Turing machine $M$, and let $s_1$, $s_2$, ... be a list of all possible strings of $\sum^{*}$. We define the enumerator $E$ as follows:
>   1. Run $M$ for $i$ steps on each input $s_1$, $s_2$, ... , $s_i$.
>   2. If any computation of $M$ accepts, print out the accepted string.

In this proof, I can't understand why do we need to run $M$ for only $i$ steps. I think the number of simulation steps may not be enough to simulate strings. Is it guaranteed that simulating $M$ finishes in $i$ steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In slightly more detail, what's happening is:

1. Run the machine on input $s_1$ for one step. If it accepts, list the string.
2. If the machine didn't halt on the previous step, run the machine on $s_1$ for one more step and then on $s_2$ for a step. As before, if the machine accepts either string, list them and remove them from consideration.
3. Do the same thing on $s_1, s_2, s_3$.
4. Continue forever.

This process, called *dovetailing*, will eventually list all and only those inputs which the TM will accept.

Comment: So does the machine continues simulating $s_i$ at next $(i + 1)^{th}$ step by running the machine just one more step if $s_i$ did not halt on the previous $i$ steps?

Comment: @AABBCC Correct.

Answer (score 1):

A language is *Turing-recognizable* (or *Recursively enumerable*) *iff* there exists a *Turing Machine* which will enumerate all valid strings of the language.

What you probably miss in the above proof is the fact that $i$ can take any value ... when we say $i$ steps, we can mean $10$, $100$, $100000$, $\infty$ steps. 
Basically $i$ is an index that indicates the number of words in the language; the enumerator $E$ could very well run forever (if the language has an  infinite number of strings).