# A language is decidable iff some enumerator enumerates it in decreasing order

Tags: undecidability

> Show that a language is decidable iff some enumerator enumerates the language in decreasing order.

What does it mean by enumerator enumerating in decreasing order? I am so confused about this concept. Can you prove the above theorem? Please help me.

Comment: You cannot prove a statement without firs understanding what it means.

Comment: If you're not sure what an exercise is asking you to do, you should contact whoever set you the exercise.

Comment: The textbook does not talk about what it means by enumerator in increasing/decreasing order. It just says enumerator is what a TM for a language prints out, and it is Turing-recognizable iff enumerator enumerates in increasing order. I am so confused about what it means by enumerating in increasing/decreasing order.

Comment: It's up to the textbook to explain what it means by *decreasing order*. I certainly have no idea. If there is no explanation of this term, I suggest ignoring this exercise.

Comment: Similar question asked recently as https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136535/regarding-a-theorem-that-says-a-language-that-is-turing-recognizable-iff-some-en

Comment: In particular, consider language $\{1^n| n \in \mathbb N\}$. For any natural definition of “decreasing”, there is no such enumerator.

Comment: even for just $\Sigma^*$, as I pointed out in the original question.